# Can't sniff Ethernet-type 0x0102 custom packet

Tags: python, networking, scapy, tcp

The first problem is that Scapy can't sniff below custom packet on Ether-type 0x0102.

calc.py ↓

```
from scapy.all import *

class calc(Packet):
    name = 'calc'
    fields_desc = [ BitEnumField('op',0,8,{1:'ADD',2:'SUM',3:'MUL'}),
                BitField('num1',0,32),
                BitField('num2',0,32)
                ]
```

send_calc.py ↓

```
from scapy.all import *
from calc import *

p = Ether(type=0x0102)/IP(dst='192.168.1.0')/ICMP()/calc(op=1,num1=2,num2=3)
sendp(p)
```

sniff_calc.py ↓

```
from scapy.all import *
from calc import *

sniff(filter='ether proto 0x0102 and host 192.168.1.0',prn=lambda x:x.show())
```

Second problem is that Scapy can sniff when set Ether-type to 0x800, but not work on 0x0102.

Further more, the result is converted custom calc() header to Raw. The following result is sniff on Ether-type 0x0800.

```
....
###[ ICMP ]### 
    type      = echo-request
    code      = 0
    chksum    = 0xf1ff
    id        = 0x0
    seq       = 0x0
###[ Raw ]### 
       load      = '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03'
```

What steps should i take so the Calc packet received would be automatically parsed and it be worked on Ether-type 0x0102? Thanks

Comment: That is not a valid EtherType, which are values >= `0x0600`. You are using the field for Length, not EtherType.

Comment: According to iana.org, 0x0101-0x01FF is used for Experimental. 
Could you tell me what is it mean?

Comment: The two EtherTypes that are designated for experimentation are `0x88b5` and `0x88b6`.

Comment: Thank you so much for kind teaching!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field in the ethernet header is only used as an EtherType field if the value is >= `0x0600`. If the field has a value <= `0x5DC`, then the field is interpreted as a payload length field.

Your value, `0x0102`, will be used as a payload length field, not as an EtherType. You need to choose a proper EtherType value. IANA maintains the [*IEEE 802 Numbers*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml) page that has the registered EtherType values, and [the IEEE maintains a page](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/ethertype/eth.txt) of *all* the assigned EtherTypes.

If you want to experiment, you need to use an EtherType assigned for that:

> 88b5
>   IEEE Std 802 - Local
>   Experimental Ethertype 1. This Ethertype value is available for public
>   use for prototype and vendor-specific protocol         development, as
>   defined in Amendment 802a to IEEE Std 802.

-or-

> 88b6
>   IEEE Std 802 - Local Experimental Ethertype 2.  This Ethertype value
>   is available for public use and for prototype and vendor-specific
>   protocol development, as defined in Amendment 802a to IEEE Std 802.